# I want to update CSV file with a different value for each line, code is returning the same value though

Tags: java, csv

my file.csv contains

```
**narendra.koribilli@uni.com**  
**stefan.hummel@uni.com**       
**ibrsduser**                      
**michel.csaba@uni.com**        
**wsdl**                           
**lalit.choudhary@uni.com**     
**Remedy Application Service**     
**vinay.k.kedlaya@uni.com**
```

I want to write these contents into another .csv file like:

```
**narendra.koribilli@uni.com**,    **some random_value()**

**stefan.hummel@uni.com**, **some random_value()**      

**ibrsduser**,**some random_value()**                      

**michel.csaba@uni.com**,**some random_value()**        

**wsdl**,**some random_value()**                           

**lalit.choudhary@uni.com**,**some random_value()**    

**Remedy Application Service**,**some random_value()**    

**vinay.k.kedlaya@uni.com**,**some random_value()**
```

In above lines some random_value() is method that generates random string for first string (i.e narendra.koribilli@uni.com)

this is what i have tried but its printing same random value for all different employee names

this is what i have tried so far

String KeyValue= "";

private static void getString() throws IOException

{

```
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream("D:\\fileUpdate.csv");

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\file.csv"));

    String str=null;

    while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        String fetch=Generate_StringForUSer(str);
        out1.println(str+","+fetch);

    }
```

}

```
private static String Generate_StringForUSer(String str) {

    int keylen=str.length();

    while (KeyValue.length () != keylen)
    {
        int rPick = r.nextInt(4);
        if (rPick == 0)
        {
            int spot = r.nextInt(25);
            KeyValue += dCase.charAt(spot);
        } 
        else if (rPick == 1) 
        {
            int spot = r.nextInt (25);
            KeyValue += uCase.charAt(spot);
        } 
        else if (rPick == 2) 
        {
            int spot = r.nextInt (7);
            KeyValue += sChar.charAt(spot);
        } 
        else if (rPick == 3)
        {
            int spot = r.nextInt (9);
            KeyValue += intChar.charAt (spot);
        }
    }
    System.out.println (KeyValue);
    return KeyValue;
```

}

Output is like this....

```
6Tui3ClnNqk#$8gCEAHxA3Er0U!V$5m
6Tui3ClnNqk#$8gCEAHxA3Er0U!V$5m
6Tui3ClnNqk#$8gCEAHxA3Er0U!V$5m
6Tui3ClnNqk#$8gCEAHxA3Er0U!V$5m
6Tui3ClnNqk#$8gCEAHxA3Er0U!V$5m
6Tui3ClnNqk#$8gCEAHxA3Er0U!V$5m
6Tui3ClnNqk#$8gCEAHxA3Er0U!V$5m
6Tui3ClnNqk#$8gCEAHxA3Er0U!V$5m
```

Same random string is generating for all users.. it should be different for different names... please tell me where i am wrong.. thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

You are using a different buffered reader while reading from the file.

Notice the `1` in

```
while((str=br1.readLine())!=null)
```

Where as you are declaring a `BufferedReader` `br`

```
 BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\file.csv"));
```

change the above while statement to

```
while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
```

To generate a String of given length, containing random characters,

**Option 1** Use `org.apache.commons.lang 's` [RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html) class.

[RandomStringUtils.random(lengthOfRequiredStr)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html#random%28int%29)

**Option 2** If you wish not to depend on the commons library, Code it yourself - Refer this [link](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/randomAlphanumericString.shtml)

Comment: @codeMan..yes i mentioned in my code, here by mistake i forgot it to mention "br1".thats ok but i am not getting different random values for different names..

Comment: @user3711467 print out the each line that you read from the br in the while loop to the console and make sure you are getting the contents of the file properly.

Comment: @user3711467 What is the type of the `KeyValue` ?

Comment: keyValue type is String.. String KeyValue="";

Comment: What is your logic to generate the random numbers?

Comment: @CodeMan...generate any random value of length equals to user names and these random values are helpful for me while reading log file. i.e i can mask those names with these generated values (this is for some clients they dont want others to see their names in log file)

Comment: @CodeMan.. random value can be of any number of occurrence of number/digits but should be same in length of user names's length. i can't extend discussion in comments.i cant chat also, not having enough reputation.

Comment: Ok. That is simple. Refer the examples in this link, You will be able to generate a random string of given size... http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/randomAlphanumericString.shtml

Comment: @CodeMan.. I have generated random string using same function for different requirements n situations but now i am not able to do that. here for me main req is to have different values rather than string length (i could do this)..